# Why does the function with the Hydra decorator return a None Type?

Tags: python, fb-hydra

This is my program:

```
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
import sys
import random
import os

input_data_path = "path/to/input/data"

@hydra.main(config_path='conf', config_name='default')
def get_number_from_sentences(cfg):
    n_sentences = cfg.n_sentences
    list_results = []
    with open(input_data_path, 'r') as input_data_file:
        input_data = input_data_file.readlines()
        for i in range(0, len(input_data), n_sentences):
            result = 0
            for sentence in input_data[i:i+n_sentences]:
                for word in sentence:
                    result = result + random.randint(0, 100)
            result = result/(n_sentences*100)
            list_results.append(result)
    return list_results

print(get_number_from_sentences())
```

The ouput is None. I can't understand why, without hydra decorator it works.

I have: Hydra 2.5, hydra-core 1.1.1

Comment: I forgot, I have omegaconf  2.1.1

Comment: The `get_number_from_sentences` function will only return a value if you pass a config object into it: `print(get_number_from_sentences(my_dictconfig_object))`. If you call `get_number_from_sentences` without an argument, then Hydra will generate a config, and Hydra will also consume the return value.

Comment: If you want to use the `@hydra.main` decorator, then all of your application logic should be orchestrated by the decorated function (e.g. you should move your `print` statement *inside* of the `get_number_from_sentences` function). If you just want to use Hydra to compose a config, you can use Hydra's [compose API](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/compose_api).